# Max stub length on digital signals

Tags: spi, signal-integrity, reflection

I have one SPI port that I'd like to use for 2 or 3 devices with chip selects.  I'm worried about signal integrity on the data lines with these stubs.  I've tried depicting my question below.

[image: Signal integrity, stubs]

Every inactive receiver on the line will now act like a stub, and delayed reflections will hit the active receiver.  How long do these stubs have to be before I'm worried?  I imagine it's frequency based. Am I okay if each stub is less than 1/10th of the clock frequency or something?  Some rule of thumb would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The critical time is not the period of the signal, but the *rise time* of the edges. The ratio is indeed somewhere around 1/10th.

If you had a 10 ns risetime, and your receiver logic was slow enough to be happy with that risetime, then your stubs should be no more than 500 ps long (1 ns round trip), or less than 100 mm on a board.

Artificially lengthening the signal risetime from your driver would work, up to a point. This is what the limited drive strength control in FPGAs is for. However, at some longer risetime, your receivers would switch poorly as the signal takes too long to pass through the invalid signal region. The data sheet for the receivers should specify a minimum risetime. Schmidt trigger input receivers are often used to tolerate longer risetimes.

You should series terminate your driver, putting a series resistance on the output to bring its total output impedance up to that of the line.

A better solution to driving a 'multi-drop' line is to terminate the far end of the line in its characteristic impedance, and to daisy-chain it from receiver to receiver, without stubs. This is sometimes called fly-by topology, and is used in DDR3 and later.

Comment: Note that, for SPI specifically, only the clock is critical as far as edge integrity (well, sometimes CS too); bounce in the other signals doesn't matter *as long as it settles before the clock edge arrives*. Note also, an end-terminated bus is difficult to do with CMOS (because the pin drive strength is close to Zo so the signal level will be about half, but the input thresholds are 30-70% Vcc usually, which will not be well met), so you need special drivers and/or receivers to implement that.

Comment: FWIW I do add 33.2 ohm resistors on every driver, I just didn't add it to the picture above.  So you're saying stubs should be less than 1/10th the rise time long, then I'm good? It's true I'm only worried about the clock line, don't want monotonicity problems double clocking the data.